# My google map (static html with JS) won't show up suddenly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

Till yesterday, the HTML map file generated by my PC application can show up.
But suddenly this morning, the Map won't show? I really have no idea 
that originally it worked and suddenly the it won't work now?
Is there any API update that causes this problem?

Can somebody help see my html file as below?
you can try to copy and paste the following HTML code to a file and save as html file, 
then click to open the HTML file and the map just won't show up?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
<script
src="http://maps.google.co.jp/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAAzr2EBOXUKnm_jVnk0OJI7xSosDVG8KKPE1-m51RBrvYughuyMxQ-i1QfUnH94QxWIa6N4U6MouMmBA&hl=ja"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var stzoom=13;
var map;
function init(){
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()){
map=new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
var mapui = map.getDefaultUI();
mapui.maptypes.physical = false;
map.setUI(mapui);
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(0,0),0);
bounds = new GLatLngBounds();
var polyOptions = {geodesic:true};
function addIcon(icon) { 
icon.iconSize = new GSize(48, 48);
icon.shadowSize = new GSize(48, 48);
icon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(24, 45);
icon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(24, 24); }
var newIcon = new GIcon();
newIcon.image = "C:/Program Files/TransTechnology/Enjoy ARES/Image/goal.png";
addIcon(newIcon);
var newIcon1 = new GIcon();
newIcon1.image = "C:/Program Files/TransTechnology/Enjoy ARES/Image/start.png";
addIcon(newIcon1);
var newIcon2 = new GIcon();
newIcon2.image = "start.png";
addIcon(newIcon2);
var point0=new GLatLng(37.85383,138.9178);
var marker0=new GMarker(point0,{icon: newIcon1});
map.addOverlay(marker0);
var point1=new GLatLng(37.85387,138.9179);
var marker1=new GMarker(point1,{icon: newIcon});
map.addOverlay(marker1);
var polyline0= new GPolyline([new GLatLng(37.85383,138.9178),
new GLatLng(37.85374,138.9176),
new GLatLng(37.85365,138.9175),
new GLatLng(37.85355,138.9173),
new GLatLng(37.85347,138.9171),
new GLatLng(37.85336,138.9169),
new GLatLng(37.85326,138.9167),
new GLatLng(37.85317,138.9165),
new GLatLng(37.85305,138.9163),
new GLatLng(37.85297,138.9161),
new GLatLng(37.8529,138.9159),
new GLatLng(37.85279,138.9157),
new GLatLng(37.85269,138.9155),
new GLatLng(37.85267,138.9157),
new GLatLng(37.85264,138.9159),
new GLatLng(37.85255,138.916),
new GLatLng(37.85291,138.9158),
new GLatLng(37.85302,138.916),
new GLatLng(37.85313,138.9162),
new GLatLng(37.85321,138.9164),
new GLatLng(37.85334,138.9167),
new GLatLng(37.85344,138.9169),
new GLatLng(37.85355,138.9172),
new GLatLng(37.8537,138.9174),
new GLatLng(37.85381,138.9177),
new GLatLng(37.85389,138.9179),
new GLatLng(37.85404,138.9181),
new GLatLng(37.854,138.9181),
new GLatLng(37.85387,138.9179)],"#ff0000", 5, 0.7, polyOptions);
map.addOverlay(polyline0);
bounds.extend(new GLatLng(37.84937, 138.9032));
bounds.extend(new GLatLng(37.87642, 138.9412));
map.setZoom(map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
}
}
window.onload=init;
</script>
</head>
<body scroll=no>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 1024px; height: 706px; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0">
<font size="5" color="#cc0000">
<div align="center">
<p><marquee></marquee></p>
<p><marquee></marquee></p>
<p><marquee></marquee></p>
<p><marquee></marquee></p>
<p><marquee></marquee></p>
<p><marquee>
We are sorry that the map cannot be shown...... 
</marquee></p>
</font></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: may i know that what you are getting the error...

Answer (score 2):

You are using the Google Maps Javascript API v2:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.co.jp/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAAzr2EBOXUKnm_jVnk0OJI7xSosDVG8KKPE1-m51RBrvYughuyMxQ-i1QfUnH94QxWIa6N4U6MouMmBA&hl=ja"type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The Google Maps Javascript API v2 has been turned down.  It has been replaced by a wrapped version of the Google Maps Javascript API v3 as advertized for the last 6 months when the original deprecation period ended.

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference):

> **Warning:** Version 2 of the Google Maps JavaScript API is no longer available for new 
>   applications and will be turned down for existing applications on **November 19, 2013**. Please 
>   follow the guide to migrate your code to version 3 of the Google Maps JavaScript API. As of 
>   **November 19, 2013**, all applications requesting v2 will be served a special, wrapped version 
>   of the v3 API instead. We expect this wrapped version of the API will work for most simple 
>   maps, but **we strongly encourage you to migrate to the v3 API immediately**.

Answer (score 2):

You're using Google maps v2, which is no longer in use.  So you have to [`upgrade to Google maps V3`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics).

Here is a simple [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/2625/) of how to use Google maps version3.