# Deprecation of V2

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I have an application calling the v2 api without key using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key="></script>
```

This has stopped working over the past couple of days. Console is showing only one error:

```
Control is no longer supported in the Google Maps Javascript API v2...
```

However, whichever way I try and call the v3 API, I get an error :

> "Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site"

I have checked, and re-connected a valid bank card to the account (although the outstanding balance was $0.00) This payment appears not to have been registered.

Any leaders on where to go next?

Comment: Apologies script tags where stripped from first example, should read:    [script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=">[/script]

Comment: Are you supplying an API key while including the script? In your sample, you've written `key=` with no value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My google map (static html with JS) won't show up suddenly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087709/my-google-map-static-html-with-js-wont-show-up-suddenly)

Comment: I think you are probably correct, and a better title would have been "unable to access v3 api" with  a copy of the code.

Comment: You can edit the question to add the code and change the title.

Comment: did you enable the Google Maps API v3-service in the console?

Comment: Can you show us how you're loading the v3 API? That seems the most relevant here. Particularly, what does the key you're using look like?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the [Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference), it is deprecated and has been turned off, replaced with a simple wrapper for the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

From the error you report in the console, the functionality you are attempting to use is not available in the wrapper.

Port your code to v3 ASAP.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, as I stated, I have tried to do just that, but am receiving an error from the API engine when trying to load the v3 script : "Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site" This is proving impossible to trace!

Comment: The code you posted uses the v2 api.  Perhaps you should post the code you are having a problem with then...

Answer (score 0):

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3#overview

You need to register a new API key.

Answer (score 0):

Loading the Google Maps API page states to use this code with a new API key placed into the code at API_KEY and you will probably need to set your sensor to FALSE, also you may need to place the new API key into your application settings page.

`<script type="text/javascript"`
`src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=FALSE">`
`</script>`

Comment: Hey user3013255 did this work for you? Wonder if you found a solution to this? thanks