# Google Maps JS API v2 stopped working

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

My maps created with Google Maps JS API v2 stopped working few days ago. In JS console I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: GLatLng is not defined

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deprecation of V2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097316/deprecation-of-v2/20098042#20098042)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that according to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/controls "Version 2 of the JavaScript API has been turned down".

> Warning: Version 2 of the Google Maps JavaScript API is no longer available. Please follow the guide to migrate your code to version 3 of the Google Maps JavaScript API. As of November 19, 2013, all applications requesting v2 are served a special, wrapped version of the v3 API instead. We expect this wrapped version of the API to work for most simple maps, but we strongly encourage you to migrate to the v3 API immediately.